# Determining percentage errors for inverse trig functions in conjunction with other errors

Tags: trigonometry, error-propagation

Let's say I have the following equation in which the unknown is $θ$:
$$tan(θ)=\frac{a}{b}$$
$$tan(θ)=\frac{5}{3}$$
$$θ=arctan(1.667)$$
$$θ=59.036°$$

Let's say the absolute errors ($∆S$) and percentage errors ($δ$) are the following:
$$∆a =0.2 $$
$$∆b =0.3 $$

$$δ_a =4 \text% $$
$$δ_b =10 \text% $$

I want to determine the percentage error ($δ$) in calculating $θ$, how do I do this?

I understand that for products and quotients, the percentage error is summed ($δ_a + δ_b$) and the percentage error for trig functions is of the format $δ =\frac{tan(θ+∆θ)-tan(θ)}{tan(θ)}*100$ but I am not sure how to proceed from here since $θ$ was calculated and not a known value with known absolute or relative errors and I am interested in the percentage error of $θ$ and not $tan(θ)$.

Someone please help, I'm melting in uncertainty abyss here :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have $\frac {\partial}{\partial x}\arctan (\frac xy)=\frac y{x^2+y^2}$ so the error in the angle due to error in $a$ is $\frac b{a^2+b^2}\Delta a$ You can do a similar thing for errors in $b$ and add them together to get the total error in $\theta$

Comment: I'm a little confused as to why that is the solution especially with taking the derivative of arctan(a/b) - looks like the opposite of trig substitution for integrals.

Comment: The derivative tells you how much the function changes for a small change in the argument.  Multiplying by the error in $a$ gives you the error in the function.